# My transaction fails with paymentResult: [paymentLineFull]

Tags: transactions, java-sdk, payments, error

I'm using the Stellar Java SDK to perform a Transaction with a PaymentOperation and I run into the following transaction response: (Converted from XDR). I don't know what this error means and how I'd fix it. Thanks for any help!

`TransactionResult
feeCharged: 100
result: [txFailed]
results: Array[1]
tr: [payment]
paymentResult: [paymentLineFull]
ext: [undefined]`

Answer (score 0):

The trustline that the recipient has set for the given asset has a limit (that's the "Trust Limit" parameter for the "ChangeTrust" operation when creating/changing a trustline). The transaction is rejected because the recipients account would exceed this limit.